# Is it possible to automatically sort A - Z these std::vectors that are the values of a std::map?

Tags: sorting, visual-c++, stdvector, stdmap

Take this simple code snippet:

```
void CDemoPickerDlg::OnBnClickedButtonSuggest()
{
    std::map<long, std::vector<CString>> mapPublishers;

    for (int iRow = 1; iRow < m_Grid.GetRowCount(); iRow++)
    {
        // Ignore publishers who are already assigned on the meeting
        const auto crBack = m_Grid.GetItemBkColour(iRow, to_underlying(EnumDemoColumn::Name));
        if (crBack != CLR_DEFAULT)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Determine last used date for this item (if any)
        const auto lDate = gsl::narrow<long>(m_Grid.GetItemData(iRow, 
            to_underlying(EnumDemoColumn::LastUsedForSpecificAssignment)));

        // Add the publisher to the right map
        const auto strPublisher = m_Grid.GetItemText(iRow, to_underlying(EnumDemoColumn::Name));
        mapPublishers[lDate].push_back(strPublisher);
    }

    const auto vPublishers = mapPublishers.at(0);

    AfxMessageBox(vPublishers.at(0));
}
```

How can I automatically have the `std::vector<CString>` sorted A - Z? The `std::map` by design is sorted in ascending date order because my `long` values are YYYYMMDD. But I would like the vectors that each date points to to be sorted A - Z.

I know how to manually sort a vector with `std::sort` but was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: You could make it `std::map<long, std::set<CString>> mapPublishers;`. Just like `std::map`, `std::set` is automatically sorted.